Threejs Phone rotate on scroll with react-three/fiber
I've created this threejs model in react-three/fiber


https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/r3f-scroll-rig-sticky-box-forked-7nkhpn?file=%2Fsrc%2FModel.js%3A9%2C30
https://7nkhpn.csb.app/
import React, { Suspense, useRef } from "react";
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { Environment } from "@react-three/drei";
import { OrbitControls, Stage } from "@react-three/drei";
import Model from "./Model";

export default function App() {
  const ref = useRef();
  const overlay = useRef();
  const caption = useRef();
  const scroll = useRef(0);
  return (
    <>
      <Canvas
        shadows
        eventSource={document.getElementById("root")}
        eventPrefix="client"
      >
        <ambientLight intensity={1} />
        <Suspense fallback={null}>
          <Model scroll={scroll} />
          <Environment preset="city" />
        </Suspense>
        <OrbitControls ref={ref} autoRotate />
      </Canvas>
    </>
  );
}

I want to get it to have it rotate on user scroll like this stickybox demo
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/r3f-scroll-rig-sticky-box-w5v4u7
function SpinningBox({ scale, scrollState, inViewport }) {
  const box = useRef()
  const size = scale.xy.min() * 0.5

  useFrame(() => {
    box.current.rotation.y = scrollState.progress * Math.PI * 2
  })

  const spring = useSpring({
    scale: inViewport ? size : size * 0.0,
    config: inViewport ? config.wobbly : config.stiff,
    delay: inViewport ? 100 : 0
  })

  return (
    <AnimatedRoundedBox ref={box} {...spring}>
      <meshNormalMaterial />
    </AnimatedRoundedBox>
  )
}

Would I just bind a ref = box to the props of the component?
similar to this
https://codepen.io/kdbkapsere/pen/wvWJmGX

latest codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/r3f-scroll-rig-sticky-box-forked-4zj88r
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Canvas, useThree } from '@react-three/fiber'
import { useGLTF, OrbitControls } from '@react-three/drei'
import gsap from 'gsap'
import { ScrollTrigger } from 'gsap/ScrollTrigger'
import * as THREE from 'three'

gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger)

const IphoneModel = () => {
  const group = useRef()
  const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF('/Iphone15.glb')

  useEffect(() => {
    const tl = gsap.timeline({
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: '#three-canvas-container',
        scrub: 1,
        //markers: true,
        pin: true,
        start: 'top top',
        end: 'bottom top'
      }
    })

    tl.to(group.current.rotation, { z: Math.PI / 8, duration: 2 })
  }, [])

  return (
    <group ref={group} dispose={null} scale={0.2} rotation={[Math.PI / 2, 0, -Math.PI / 8]}>
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Cameras.geometry} material={materials.cam} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Glass.geometry} material={materials['glass.001']} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Metal_Rough.geometry} material={materials.metal_rough} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Metal_Shiny.geometry} material={materials.metal_Shiny} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Plastic.geometry} material={materials.metal_rough} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Portal.geometry} material={materials['M_Base.001']} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Screen.geometry} material={materials.Screen} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Speakers.geometry} material={materials.metal_rough} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_USB.geometry} material={materials.metal_rough} />
    </group>
  )
}

const Background = () => {
  const { scene } = useThree()
  useEffect(() => {
    scene.background = new THREE.Color('#555555')
  }, [scene])

  return null
}

const TextSection = () => {
  const textRefs = useRef([])

  useEffect(() => {
    gsap.fromTo(
      textRefs.current,
      { opacity: 0 },
      {
        opacity: 1,
        stagger: 0.1,
        scrollTrigger: {
          trigger: '#text-trigger',
          start: 'top bottom',
          end: 'center center',
          scrub: 1,
          markers: false
        }
      }
    )
  }, [])

  const texts = ['Ready 5', 'Ready 4', 'Ready 3', 'Ready 2', 'Ready 1']

  return (
    <div
      id="text-trigger"
      style={{
        height: '100vh',
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        position: 'relative',
        top: '500px'
      }}>
      {texts.map((text, index) => (
        <h1 key={index} ref={(el) => (textRefs.current[index] = el)} style={{ opacity: 0 }}>
          {text}
        </h1>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

const ThreeScene = () => (
  <div id="three-canvas-container" style={{ width: '100vw', height: '500px' }}>
    <Canvas camera={{ position: [0, 0, 10], fov: 45 }} gl={{ antialias: true, alpha: false }}>
      <ambientLight intensity={0.4} />
      <directionalLight position={[5, 10, 7.5]} intensity={1} />
      <IphoneModel />
      <OrbitControls enableZoom={false} />
      <Background />
    </Canvas>
  </div>
)

const App = () => (
  <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', height: '400vh' }}>
    <div className="some-content" style={{ height: '100vh', display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <h1>ACTION</h1>
    </div>
    <ThreeScene />
    <TextSection />
  </div>
)

export default App

-- using a youtube embed into the mesh
  <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Screen.geometry} material={materials.Screen}>
    <Html occlude="true" transform rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]} position={[0, 0.6, 0]} scale={[1, 1, 1]}>
      <div style={{ width: '278px', height: '580px', background: 'white', borderRadius: '50px' }}>
        <iframe
          src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/oGtQKF62ZYg"
          style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', border: 'none', borderRadius: 'inherit' }}
          title="video"
        />
      </div>
    </Html>
  </mesh>


using local video
  <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Screen.geometry} material={materials.Screen}>
    <Html occlude="true" transform rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]} position={[0, 0.6, 0]} scale={[1, 1, 1]}>
      <div style={{ width: '278px', height: '580px', background: 'white', borderRadius: '50px' }}>
        <video width="278" height="580" autoplay style={{ width: '278px', height: '580px', background: 'white', borderRadius: '50px' }}>
          <source
            src="https://videos.ctfassets.net/f1onadsih6xk/5xdqjOZgZHvYos0cTRB4D6/4b5a6b47bc9e46d5ed3bfc8edd780da6/DocumentInSeconds.mp4"
            type="video/mp4"
          />
          Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
      </div>
    </Html>

Better way of adding the video so the speaker part still shows is modifying the screen material.
  useEffect(() => {
    const video = document.createElement('video')
    video.src = 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/video/2024/07/14/221180_tiny.mp4'
    video.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'
    video.loop = true
    video.muted = true
    video.play()

    const videoTexture = new THREE.VideoTexture(video)
    videoTexture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter
    videoTexture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter
    videoTexture.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding

    materials.Screen.map = videoTexture
    materials.Screen.needsUpdate = true

    const tl = gsap.timeline({
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: '#three-canvas-container',
        scrub: 1,
        markers: true,
        pin: true,
        start: 'top top',
        end: 'bottom top'
      }
    })

    tl.to(group.current.rotation, { z: Math.PI * 2, duration: 2 })
  }, [materials.Screen])


First sandbox doesn't work.

I don't know why that is - on my local the code works

I'm trying understand your issue, but is hard to me from this gif, and code which you pasted only change your rotation. I think, try make new Sandbox and paste URL, or elaborate tour expectations in post edit.

Well also need to add video/image -   https://videos.ctfassets.net/f1onadsih6xk/1SswaYYtFZR6dTOsFMurFW/3539e30d062e39f01cd84a426164adc1/Exo_Works_-_ReviewImagesAnywhere.mp4   or/and  https://videos.ctfassets.net/f1onadsih6xk/1v3hNplvIPRuHnIW7qpIpd/7c6264abecf4981600e50af99e5b0e8a/Billing_Made_Easy.mp4

I figured out later, what you were talking about, check me update, please.

You can do this in several ways. You can use some frame to place the canvas as part of a scrolling DOM with other elements. You can completely fill the view with the canvas and create the entire scrolling logic from scratch with each specific event calculated. And this seems to be the best solution, especially when you remove the native scrollbar. However, this will also have its limitations, such as the inability to use ScrollTrigger, you will have to use another way of listening for elements to enter the part of the viewport you are interested in, and firing specific events. This will have great benefits, especially on mobile devices, with the cumbersome and unsightly recalculation of the canvas. But with a complex project, it's time-consuming...
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Canvas, useThree } from '@react-three/fiber'
import { useGLTF, OrbitControls } from '@react-three/drei'
import gsap from 'gsap'
import { ScrollTrigger } from 'gsap/ScrollTrigger'
import * as THREE from 'three'

gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger)

const IphoneModel = () => {
  const group = useRef()
  const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF('/Iphone15.glb')

  useEffect(() => {
    const tl = gsap.timeline({
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: '#three-canvas-container',
        scrub: 1,
        markers: true,
        pin: true,
        start: 'top top',
        end: 'bottom top'
      }
    })

    tl.to(group.current.rotation, { z: Math.PI * 2, duration: 2 })

  }, [])

  return (
    <group ref={group} dispose={null} scale={0.2} rotation={[Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]}>
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Cameras.geometry} material={materials.cam} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Glass.geometry} material={materials['glass.001']} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Metal_Rough.geometry} material={materials.metal_rough} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Metal_Shiny.geometry} material={materials.metal_Shiny} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Plastic.geometry} material={materials.metal_rough} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Portal.geometry} material={materials['M_Base.001']} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Screen.geometry} material={materials.Screen} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Speakers.geometry} material={materials.metal_rough} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_USB.geometry} material={materials.metal_rough} />
    </group>
  )
}

const Background = () => {
  const { scene } = useThree()
  useEffect(() => {
    scene.background = new THREE.Color('#555555')
  }, [scene])

  return null
}

const TextSection = () => {
  const textRefs = useRef([])

  useEffect(() => {
    gsap.fromTo(
      textRefs.current,
      { opacity: 0 },
      {
        opacity: 1,
        stagger: 0.1,
        scrollTrigger: {
          trigger: '#text-trigger',
          start: 'top bottom',
          end: 'center center',
          scrub: 1,
          markers: false
        }
      }
    )
  }, [])

  const texts = ['Ready 5', 'Ready 4', 'Ready 3', 'Ready 2', 'Ready 1']

  return (
    <div
      id="text-trigger"
      style={{
        height: '100vh',
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        position: 'relative',
        top: '500px'
      }}>
      {texts.map((text, index) => (
        <h1 key={index} ref={(el) => (textRefs.current[index] = el)} style={{ opacity: 0 }}>
          {text}
        </h1>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

const ThreeScene = () => (
  <div id="three-canvas-container" style={{ width: '100vw', height: '500px' }}>
    <Canvas camera={{ position: [0, 0, 10], fov: 45 }} gl={{ antialias: true, alpha: false }}>
      <ambientLight intensity={0.4} />
      <directionalLight position={[5, 10, 7.5]} intensity={1} />
      <IphoneModel />
      <OrbitControls enableZoom={false} />
      <Background />
    </Canvas>
  </div>
)

const App = () => (
  <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', height: '400vh' }}>
    <div className="some-content" style={{ height: '100vh', display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <h1>ACTION</h1>
    </div>
    <ThreeScene />
    <TextSection />
  </div>
)

export default App

SANDBOX
EDIT
Rotating iFrame
<group ref={group} dispose={null} scale={0.2} rotation={[Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]}>
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Cameras.geometry} material={materials.cam} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Glass.geometry} material={materials['glass.001']} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Metal_Rough.geometry} material={materials.metal_rough} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Metal_Shiny.geometry} material={materials.metal_Shiny} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Plastic.geometry} material={materials.metal_rough} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Portal.geometry} material={materials['M_Base.001']} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Screen.geometry} material={materials.Screen}>
        <Html occlude="true" transform rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]} position={[0, 0.6, 0]} scale={[1, 1, 1]}>
          <div style={{ width: '278px', height: '580px', background: 'white', borderRadius: '50px' }}>
            <iframe
              src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/oGtQKF62ZYg"
              style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', border: 'none', borderRadius: 'inherit' }}
              title="video"
            />
          </div>
        </Html>
      </mesh>
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Speakers.geometry} material={materials.metal_rough} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_USB.geometry} material={materials.metal_rough} />
    </group>

EDIT 2
Video texture
const IphoneModel = () => {
  const group = useRef()
  const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF('/Iphone15.glb')

  useEffect(() => {
    const video = document.createElement('video')
    video.src = 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/video/2024/07/14/221180_tiny.mp4'
    video.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'
    video.loop = true
    video.muted = true
    video.play()

    const videoTexture = new THREE.VideoTexture(video)
    videoTexture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter
    videoTexture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter
    videoTexture.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding

    materials.Screen.map = videoTexture
    materials.Screen.needsUpdate = true

    const tl = gsap.timeline({
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: '#three-canvas-container',
        scrub: 1,
        markers: true,
        pin: true,
        start: 'top top',
        end: 'bottom top'
      }
    })

    tl.to(group.current.rotation, { z: Math.PI * 2, duration: 2 })
  }, [materials.Screen])

  return (
    <group ref={group} dispose={null} scale={0.2} rotation={[Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]}>
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Cameras.geometry} material={materials.cam} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Glass.geometry} material={materials['glass.001']} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Metal_Rough.geometry} material={materials.metal_rough} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Metal_Shiny.geometry} material={materials.metal_Shiny} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Plastic.geometry} material={materials.metal_rough} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Portal.geometry} material={materials['M_Base.001']} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Screen.geometry} material={materials.Screen}>
        {/* Video Texture */}
      </mesh>
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Speakers.geometry} material={materials.metal_rough} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_USB.geometry} material={materials.metal_rough} />
    </group>
  )
}

Texture
const IphoneModel = () => {
  const group = useRef()
  const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF('/Iphone15.glb')

  useEffect(() => {
    const imageTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(
      'https://pixabay.com/get/gc7b67400496e98a63a3c56eae484aa0bbb9163a92866e2588bcf817c8f164853cf8b7153fc1710f8b90ab5e27c9efd8b24dda4bd9238ef937a5474638ceba83536155b6ac9bf2b91f8eebcad2d36519c_640.jpg'
    )
    materials.Screen.map = imageTexture
    materials.Screen.needsUpdate = true

    const tl = gsap.timeline({
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: '#three-canvas-container',
        scrub: 1,
        markers: true,
        pin: true,
        start: 'top top',
        end: 'bottom top'
      }
    })

    tl.to(group.current.rotation, { z: Math.PI * 2, duration: 2 })
  }, [materials.Screen])

  return (
    <group ref={group} dispose={null} scale={0.2} rotation={[Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]}>
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Cameras.geometry} material={materials.cam} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Glass.geometry} material={materials['glass.001']} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Metal_Rough.geometry} material={materials.metal_rough} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Metal_Shiny.geometry} material={materials.metal_Shiny} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Plastic.geometry} material={materials.metal_rough} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Portal.geometry} material={materials['M_Base.001']} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Screen.geometry} material={materials.Screen}>
        {/* Texture */}
      </mesh>
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Speakers.geometry} material={materials.metal_rough} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_USB.geometry} material={materials.metal_rough} />
    </group>
  )
}


this is great - I think I got it close to the rotations as a reference - https://4zj88r.csb.app/ -- how would you modify this to have an image/video in the phone - so it all turns together - we have to create a new mesh inside the group?

I'm not sure on that - https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/r3f-scroll-rig-sticky-box-forked-4zj88r

I don't know - I just modified some of the rotation -I'll put the code in the body of the post

I've seen in the reference site I looked at - its loading in a video from an img tag --- 

Yes but I would propose the localhost mp4 - then like a youtube embed - because the size is likely to mobile-size - if it were a laptop model the widescreen youtube could be ok -- be good to expose it as a non-youtube embed - just using an mp4 or an image

I was able to use a video tag -- I noticed in your youtube embed and the video tag method -- it actually covers up the speakers of the phone - the little rounded box top - I am not sure how you can control the index - or why its over ridden - and also layering the order of the meshes has no effect.

@TheOldCounty I updated code with video and texture, respecting speaker in screen.

That's really good - thank you.

The only other concern is if you had multiple phones - to step away from using an id - but then maybe your selector would become a react ref?

Sure you can, to manege them individually, that should not impact performance to much, of course depends how many you need them ;). Look at some tips here

This is the closest I have got so far - 20th Sep
see deep example -- https://www.exo.inc/iris


replacing image with video on half cycle (when the phone is turned around)
adding the egg shell gradient background
adding the svg morph semi-circle basin to diamond

it renders a video and spins around twice in the same direction
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/r3f-scroll-rig-sticky-box-forked-279mp3
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Canvas, useThree } from '@react-three/fiber'
import { useGLTF, OrbitControls } from '@react-three/drei'
import gsap from 'gsap'
import { ScrollTrigger } from 'gsap/ScrollTrigger'
import * as THREE from 'three'

gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger)

const IphoneModel = (props) => {
  const group = useRef()
  const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF('/Iphone15.glb')

  useEffect(() => {
    const video = document.createElement('video')
    video.src = props.mediaAsset
    video.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'
    video.loop = true
    video.muted = true
    video.play()

    const videoTexture = new THREE.VideoTexture(video)
    videoTexture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter
    videoTexture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter
    videoTexture.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding

    videoTexture.wrapS = videoTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping
    videoTexture.anisotropy = 16
    videoTexture.repeat = new THREE.Vector2(1, -1)

    materials.Screen.map = videoTexture

    let screenMaterial = materials.Screen.clone()
    screenMaterial.map = videoTexture

    //materials.Screen.map = imageTexture
    materials.Screen = screenMaterial

    materials.Screen.needsUpdate = true

    const tl = gsap.timeline({
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: '#three-canvas-container',
        scrub: 1,
        //markers: true,
        pin: true,
        start: 'top top',
        end: 'bottom top'
      }
    })

    tl.to(group.current.rotation, { z: -Math.PI * 4, duration: 2 })
  }, [materials.Screen])

  return (
    <group ref={group} dispose={null} scale={0.2} rotation={[Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]}>
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Cameras.geometry} material={materials.cam} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Glass.geometry} material={materials['glass.001']} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Metal_Rough.geometry} material={materials.metal_rough} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Metal_Shiny.geometry} material={materials.metal_Shiny} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Plastic.geometry} material={materials.metal_rough} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Portal.geometry} material={materials['M_Base.001']} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Screen.geometry} material={materials.Screen} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Speakers.geometry} material={materials.metal_rough} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_USB.geometry} material={materials.metal_rough} />
    </group>
  )
}

const Background = () => {
  const { scene } = useThree()
  useEffect(() => {
    scene.background = new THREE.Color('#555555')
  }, [scene])

  return null
}

const TextSection = () => {
  const textRefs = useRef([])

  useEffect(() => {
    gsap.fromTo(
      textRefs.current,
      { opacity: 0 },
      {
        opacity: 1,
        stagger: 0.1,
        scrollTrigger: {
          trigger: '#text-trigger',
          start: 'top bottom',
          end: 'center center',
          scrub: 1,
          markers: false
        }
      }
    )
  }, [])

  const texts = ['Ready 5', 'Ready 4', 'Ready 3', 'Ready 2', 'Ready 1']

  return (
    <div
      id="text-trigger"
      style={{
        height: '100vh',
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        position: 'relative',
        top: '500px'
      }}>
      {texts.map((text, index) => (
        <h1 key={index} ref={(el) => (textRefs.current[index] = el)} style={{ opacity: 0 }}>
          {text}
        </h1>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

const ThreeScene = (mediaAsset) => (
  <div id="three-canvas-container" style={{ width: '100vw', height: '500px' }}>
    <Canvas camera={{ position: [0, 0, 10], fov: 45 }} gl={{ antialias: true, alpha: false }}>
      <ambientLight intensity={0.4} />
      <directionalLight position={[5, 10, 7.5]} intensity={1} />
      <IphoneModel mediaAsset={mediaAsset.mediaAsset} />
      <OrbitControls enableZoom={false} />
      <Background />
    </Canvas>
  </div>
)

const App = () => {
  let item = { videoUrl: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/video/2020/06/04/41128-427876270_large.mp4' }

  return (
    <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', height: '400vh' }}>
      <div className="some-content" style={{ height: '100vh', display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <h1>ACTION</h1>
      </div>
      <ThreeScene mediaAsset={item.videoUrl} />
      <TextSection />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App

